# need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: python

```
movies = defaultdict(int)
for line in open('trial.txt', "r"):
    user,movie,rating,time = line.rstrip('\n').split('::')
    movies[movie] += 1
```

---

For the following line, there always occurs error that I don't understand:

```
user, movie, rating,time = line.rstrip('\n').split('::')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I can always print out the line and it is really with 4 parts
What's wrong? thank you!

Comment: Have you checked if the line is blank?

Comment: What is your input file like?

Comment: I have checked, it is not blank.
the data is like :1267::47999::0.5::1188678492
originally in .dat

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are blank lines in your file. You have to skip them to avoid this error, or at least check that the number of values you want to unpack are correct:

```
movies = defaultdict(int)
for line in open('trial.txt', "r"):
    values = line.rstrip('\n').split('::')
    if len(values) == 4:
        user,movie,rating,time = values
        movies[movie] += 1
    else:
        print "Non-valid format: %s" % line
```

Comment: that's cool! thank you so much. I checked the dataset and did not find any blank actually. How could you know it? thanks.

Comment: @TonyGuangyuTong Glad it helped, feel free to accept the answer if it solved your problem.